# My cost function is not able to minimize below 0.2.I am using IRIS dataset to test my network

Tags: java, neural-network, deep-learning, perceptron

This is my first neural network and I built it ground up in Java without using any of the ML packages. This is my first experience in ML or deep learning.

When I pass a single datapoint as input, the cost function minimises till 10^-5 but once I start adding more datapoints the cost function increases significantly and the accuracy decreases.

I have noticed that both the weight and bias gradients are vanishing.
Edit:my net works with 2 layers but when i add more layers the cost increases.Why is that?

```java
import java.util.*;
public class backprop
{
    Network hidden[];double learningrate; double expects[];
    backprop(Network k[],double learn,double expected[])
    {
        hidden=k;learningrate=learn;expects=expected;
    }

    double dsigmoid(double x)
    {
        return(x*(1.0-x));
    }

    void expect()
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        hidden[hidden.length-1].expected=new double[expects.length];
        hidden[hidden.length-1].expected=expects;
        /*for(int a=0;a<hidden[hidden.length-1].expected.length;a++)
        {
        //System.out.println("expected:"+(a+1));
        hidden[hidden.length-1].expected[a]=expects[a];
        }*/
    }

    void error(int a)
    {
        hidden[a].error=new double[hidden[a].weightsum.length];
        Matrix A=new Matrix(hidden[a].expected,hidden[a].weightsum.length,0);
        Matrix B=new Matrix(hidden[a].weightsum,hidden[a].weightsum.length,0);
        Matrix C=B.minus(A);
        hidden[a].error=C.toSDA().data1;
    }

    void hiddenerror(int a)
    {
        hidden[a].error=new double[hidden[a].weightsum.length];double ary[]=new double[hidden[a+1].weightsum.length];
        for(int a1=0;a1<hidden[a+1].weightsum.length;a1++)
        {
            for(int a2=0;a2<hidden[a].weightsum.length;a2++)
                 ary[a1]+=hidden[a].link[a2].weight[a1];
        }
        for(int a1=0;a1<hidden[a].weightsum.length;a1++)
        {
            for(int a2=0;a2<hidden[a+1].weightsum.length;a2++)
                hidden[a].error[a1]+=(hidden[a].link[a1].weight[a2]/(ary[a2]))*hidden[a+1].error[a2];
        }
    }
    //check again
    void changeweights(int a)
    {
        for(int a2=0;a2<hidden[a+1].weightsum.length;a2++)
        {
            for(int a1=0;a1<hidden[a].weightsum.length;a1++)
            {
               // System.out.println(hidden[a+1].error[a2]*dsigmoid(hidden[a+1].weightsum[a2])*hidden[a].weightsum[a1]+" ");
                hidden[a].link[a1].weight[a2]=hidden[a].link[a1].weight[a2]-(learningrate*hidden[a+1].error[a2]*dsigmoid(hidden[a+1].weightsum[a2])*hidden[a].weightsum[a1]);
            }
        }for(int a1=0;a1<hidden[a+1].weightsum.length;a1++)
        {
            //System.out.println(hidden[a+1].error[a1]*dsigmoid(hidden[a+1].weightsum[a1])+" ");
            hidden[a+1].link[a1].bias=hidden[a+1].link[a1].bias-(learningrate*hidden[a+1].error[a1]*dsigmoid(hidden[a+1].weightsum[a1]));
        } System.out.println();
    }

    void main()
    {
        expect();double cost=0;
        error(hidden.length-1);
        for(int a=hidden.length-2;a>0;a--)
            hiddenerror(a);
        for(int a=hidden.length-2;a>=0;a--)
            changeweights(a);
        for(int a=0;a<hidden[hidden.length-1].error.length;a++)
        {cost+=Math.pow(hidden[hidden.length-1].error[a],2);
            //System.out.print(hidden[hidden.length-1].error[a]+" ");
        }
        cost=cost/hidden[hidden.length-1].error.length;
        System.out.println(cost);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without having much more details about your problem. What architecture are you using? Is the network big enough to solve the problem? Which loss are you minimising? Please edit your post to provide more details. As a first try, you should try to train on a single, smallish batch of say 32 images. This you should be able to completely overfit if your network is big enough.

Comment: i am randomly training but i am not splitting them into batches.Could this be the problem?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Can you show some code? If you are using stochastic gradient descent, you should definitely use batches in order to converge. But convergence depends on many other parameters, we need more details, and some code would be best.

Comment: What part? backpropogation?And how do i add code here?

Comment: Both back propagation and the optimisation part (gradient descent) would be the first places to check. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000 for instructions on how to add code blocks to your question.

Comment: Debugging this kind of numerical problem can be very time-consuming. Here is a good post for how to approach the problem: http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/

Comment: @PranavDave Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.